# invalid syntax because of 'OR' operation in python

Tags: python

```
straightrunfaces = 'A23456789TJQKA';
for i in range(0,10):
        if ((counts[straightrunfaces[i]] and 
             counts[straightrunfaces[i+1]] and 
             counts[straightrunfaces[i+2]] and 
             counts[straightrunfaces[i+3]])) or
            ((counts[straightrunfaces[i+1]] and 
             counts[straightrunfaces[i+2]] and 
             counts[straightrunfaces[i+3]] and 
             counts[straightrunfaces[i+4]])):



C:\datasci_course_materials\assignment3>python poker.py
  File "poker.py", line 62
    counts[straightrunfaces[i+3]])) or
                                     ^
**SyntaxError: invalid syntax**
```

I don't understand why the 'OR' operator is not working

Comment: why do you have a double `((..))` - get rid of one of it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem isn't the `or`, it's the newline at the end. There are no open parentheses anymore, so the newline terminates the `if` statement; however, an `if` statement must end in a colon, and yours doesn't, to the parser.

Either add an explicit line continuation:

```
if (counts[straightrunfaces[i]] and 
    counts[straightrunfaces[i+1]] and 
    counts[straightrunfaces[i+2]] and 
    counts[straightrunfaces[i+3]]) or \
   (counts[straightrunfaces[i+1]] and 
    counts[straightrunfaces[i+2]] and 
    counts[straightrunfaces[i+3]] and 
    counts[straightrunfaces[i+4]]):
```

Or wrap the whole thing in parentheses:

```
if ((counts[straightrunfaces[i]] and 
     counts[straightrunfaces[i+1]] and 
     counts[straightrunfaces[i+2]] and 
     counts[straightrunfaces[i+3]]) or
    (counts[straightrunfaces[i+1]] and 
     counts[straightrunfaces[i+2]] and 
     counts[straightrunfaces[i+3]] and 
     counts[straightrunfaces[i+4]])):
```

[PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
straightrunfaces = 'A23456789TJQKA';
for i in range(0,10):
    if all(counts[straightrunfaces[i]], counts[straightrunfaces[i+1]], counts[straightrunfaces[i+2]], counts[straightrunfaces[i+3]]) or all(counts[straightrunfaces[i+1]], counts[straightrunfaces[i+2]], counts[straightrunfaces[i+3]], counts[straightrunfaces[i+4]]):
```